# Extend a <div> element off of the screen as opposed to wrapping the content

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to make it so that a `<div>` that contains other smaller `<div>` elements (which are floated left) disappears off of the screen, rather than wrapping, but I can't figure it out.

You can see an example of the problem here - http://pictures.dnsdiag.com/

Below is the CSS that I have so far, and here is a link to a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQAH4/). Can someone please help me figure this out.

```
.banner{
    background: rgba(153,153,153,0.6);
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#author-links.banner{
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#author-links .author-link{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#author-links .author-link span.preview-image{
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

In case anyone is wondering, the reason why I wish to do this is so that I can include a jQuery plugin that will allow the user to scroll through the pictures (in a more esthetically pleasing manner than the horizontal scroll bar). Thanks.

Comment: Don't get it. You want them to "dissapear"? Like "flow-out" of the window area? Make external div overflow:hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[View working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eQAH4/2/)**

In `.banner{` add `white-space: nowrap;`

In `#author-links .author-link` change `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` and remove `float: left`;

```
.banner{
    background: rgba(153,153,153,0.6);
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#author-links .author-link{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/eQAH4/1/

```
#author-links{
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* rest of your styles... */
}
```

and

```
#author-links .author-link {
    display: inline-block;
    /* float:left; REMOVED */
    /* rest of your styles... */
}
```